# Restore a SQL Server DB.bak in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am running a .NET Razor application, an instance of gitea, and a SQL Server database each in separate containers that communicate with one another. I would like to start my database image with a database schema and data (by restoring a `.bak` file).

I can do this with my current Dockerfile, if once it is up and running, I run these additional commands:

1. `docker exec -it myContainer /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlsmd -S localhost -U sa -P myPassword`
2. `/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P myPassword -Q "RESTORE DATABASE MY_DB_NAME FROM DISK='/var/opt/mssql/backup/MY_DB_NAME.bak' WITH MOVE 'MY_DB_NAME_TEST' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/MY_DB_NAME_TEST.mdf', MOVE 'MY_DB_NAME_TEST_log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/MY_DB_NAME_TEST_log.ldf'"`

This gets the job done, but I want to fully automate the process so that this is configured 100% by my docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile so I need only type: `docker-compose up -d`.

I don't think the content of my docker-compose.yml file is relevant, but here is my Dockerfile (where I am trying to run that script that I currently need to run after `docker-compose up`):

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux

ENV SA_PASSWORD=myPassword
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y

COPY ./ACES_DB.bak /var/opt/mssql/backup/MY_DB_NAME.bak
RUN docker exec -it myContainer bin/sh /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P myPassword -Q "RESTORE DATABASE MY_DB_NAME FROM DISK='/var/opt/mssql/backup/MY_DB_NAME.bak' WITH MOVE 'MY_DB_NAME_TEST' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/MY_DB_NAME_TEST.mdf', MOVE 'MY_DB_NAME_TEST_log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/MY_DB_NAME_TEST_log.ldf'"
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A friend and I puzzled through this together and eventually found this solution. Here's what the docker file looks like:

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux
ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=myPassword
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y

COPY ./My_DB.bak /var/opt/mssql/backup/My_DB.bak
COPY restore.sql restore.sql
RUN (/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & ) | grep -q "Starting database restore" && /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P 'myPassword' -d master -i restore.sql
```

*Note that I moved the SQL restore statement to a .sql file.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on @joshua-abbott 's answer. Here is my setup for restoring multiple DB to mssql 2019 docker image, and replacing the 'default' password used to restore the DB.

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
ENV DEFAULT_MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=myStrongDefaultPassword
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
USER root

COPY restore-db.sh entrypoint.sh /opt/mssql/bin/
RUN chmod +x /opt/mssql/bin/restore-db.sh /opt/mssql/bin/entrypoint.sh

ADD data.tar.gz /var/opt/mssql/
RUN chown -R mssql:root /var/opt/mssql/data && \
                chmod 0755 /var/opt/mssql/data && \
                chmod -R 0650 /var/opt/mssql/data/*

USER mssql
RUN /opt/mssql/bin/restore-db.sh
CMD [ "/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr" ]
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/mssql/bin/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

restore-db.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

export MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=$DEFAULT_MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD
(/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & ) | grep -q "Server is listening on" && sleep 2

for restoreFile in /var/opt/mssql/data/*.bak
do
    fileName=${restoreFile##*/}
    base=${fileName%.bak}
    /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P $MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [$base] FROM DISK = '$restoreFile'"
    rm -rf $restoreFile
done
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd \
    -l 60 \
    -S localhost -U SA -P "$DEFAULT_MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD" \
    -Q "ALTER LOGIN SA WITH PASSWORD='${MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD}'" &

/opt/mssql/bin/permissions_check.sh "$@"
```

Comment: If I understand your build/run process correctly, you start the server (using /opt/mssql/bin/sqlserver) in line 3 of restore-db.sh. In your entrypoint, you don't start the server (since it is already started), instead you run sqlcmd, which allows the user to execute sql statements if the container is started interactively?

This is interesting but differs quite a lot from the run process of "default r.microsoft.com/mssql/server". These containers will start the server (using /opt/mssql/bin/sqlserver) only when the container starts.

Answer (score 2):

I voted for the answer of @Joshua Abbott , but I needed to customize the answer to match the question i.e. to restore from .bak file as it was required:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
 
        ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
        ENV SA_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
        ENV MSSQL_PID=Developer
        ENV MSSQL_TCP_PORT=1433 
        
        WORKDIR /src
        
        COPY ["API/db/db.bak", "dbbackups/"]

        RUN (/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & ) | grep -q "Starting database restore" && /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P 'xxxxxxxx' -Q "RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK='/dbbackups/db.bak';"
```

just you need to change xxxxxxx with your password, you can name your container as you want using the docker compose file/override files

Comment: I think, FILELISTONLY just lists the contents, though

Comment: Check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69510163/4201816

I used "RESTORE DATABASE [file] FROM DISK = 'file.bak'"

Answer (score 1):

One thing Joshua forgot to add was the sql script:

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=MyPassword1!
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y

COPY MyDatabase.bak /var/opt/mssql/data/

COPY restore-database.sql /var/opt/mssql/data/

RUN /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'MyPassword1!' -Q "EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'IF (''?'' != ''master'' AND ''?'' != ''tempdb'' AND ''?'' != ''model'' AND ''?'' != ''msdb'' ) BEGIN EXEC (''?'' .dbo.sp_changedbowner ''''sa'''') END'"
CMD /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'MyPassword1!' -d master -i /var/opt/mssql/data/restore-database.sql
```

restore-database.sql

```
RESTORE DATABBASE MyDatabase
FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/data/MyDatabase.bak'
WITH MOVE 'MyDatabase' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/MyDatabase.mdf'
MOVE 'MyDatabase_log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/MyDatabase_log.ldf'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, I use SQL Server Management Studio, when you create your DOCKER you declare a var for the directory, just put de Backup there and then you just restore it on your SQL

[image]

[image]

You can create a stored procedure in one of your databases for creating an automatic backup, I found this an made some adaptations for my use.

```
------ If you create this and then execute it------

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_M_Backup]
AS
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- database name  
    DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- path for backup files  
    DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- filename for backup  
    DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20) -- used for file name

    -- specify database backup directory
    SET @path = '/var/opt/mssql/data/Backup/'  
     
    -- specify filename format
    SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) 
     
    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR  
        SELECT name 
        FROM master.sys.databases 
        WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb', 'Eikon_CDEEE')  -- exclude these databases
          AND state = 0 -- database is online
          AND is_in_standby = 0 -- database is not read only for log shipping
     
    OPEN db_cursor   
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
     
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN   
        SET @fileName = @path + @name + '_' + @fileDate + '.BAK'  

        BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName  
     
        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
    END   
    
    CLOSE db_cursor   
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor
    
    /** SET @path = '/var/opt/mssql/data/Backup/'   the mssql/data/ is my directory where I have mounted the SQL Server from Docker, and Backup is a directory inside this directory, so you have to change it for your directory**/
```